# jquery autocomplete not found in app rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I work on a rails project and I have a problem with a plugin of jquery : autocomplete.
    I try to implemete a search engine with multiple word, I include in my webpage 1.8.0.min.js and the plugin autocomplete (jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js) and the code  below in another .js include too:

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
    var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Scheme"
    ];
    function split( val ) {
    return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
    return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#search" ).bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
           $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
           event.preventDefault();
        }
 })
     .autocomplete({
     minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
        response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
        availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        focus: function() {
       // prevent value inserted on focus
       return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
        var terms = split( this.value );
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push( ui.item.value );
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push( "" );
        this.value = terms.join( ", " );
        return false;
        }
    });
});
```

In my app this code don't work and firebug give me this warning:

```
    TypeError: $("#search").bind("keydown", function (event) {if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {event.preventDefault();}}).autocomplete is not a function
    TypeError: $("#search").bind("keydown", function (e) {e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active && e.preventDefault();}).autocomplete is not a function
```

When I test this outside of my app it's work.
I'm on Mandriva 12.04 TLS, and a use firefox 15.0.

Comment: probably you are missing a library in your page . if you are sure that you have everything included , some times it's important how you are including them . some library should be above the others for example you should put jquery above all and so on ...

Comment: Where is the code (in your layout) where you include the jquery libraries?